# Taking a sail batten on a plane

Tags: uk, hand-luggage

I'm flying from the UK with a sail in my hold luggage. One of the battens is too big and won't fit. Can I carry it on as hand luggage or would it not be allowed through security?

It looks like this. Is approx 80cm x 1cm tapering from 8mm to 3mm with plastic caps glued onto either end. It is made out of a fibreglass-like material.
[image: Sail Batten]

Comment: Are there sharp ends under those plastic caps?

Comment: I can't tell, the plastic caps are glued on, so don't remove easily and I don't want to damage it. I would assume that the edges would be square and not smooth or tapering to sharp. The measurements I gave above is my estimate for the size of the ends under the caps.

Comment: Given that people check skis into luggage, why do you think you can't check this into your luggage (assuming suitably packed)?

Comment: The bag I'm checking-in is too small

Comment: Tape them together & attach a luggage tag. They don't have to be in a bag to be checked in.

Comment: That's one small bag if you can't get an 80 cm object to fit in diagonally.  The minimum size you need is 60cmx60cm.  Thats not much bigger than the maximum hand luggage size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be on the safe side.

Buy a cardboard tube and pack your sail baton with bubble wrap; leave one side easily accessible if security wants to look at it (keep some tapes with you if wanting to secure it if needed).

Mark it with your name/address... put on a "fragile" sticker on it.

When doing your check-in at the counter, ask if you can bring it with you, if yes, then YEAH!, if not, then just check in the prepared tube.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where you won't know until you try.  Technically, the batten is not a prohibited item and meets the liner requirements of most airline rules but it is still an odd shape.

You should be able to **stow it like a cane**.

They're pretty sturdy, but I would at least wrap it in something.